# Group By one attribute by another attribute of Object

Tags: java, group-by

can anyone help me. I have a list of Objects - in my case there are breweries.
Each brewerie has some attributes(fields) like name, adress, id, province(the state where is situated) etc... One brewerie (name) can be situated in many provinces. Now i need solve the problem: how to take number of breweries in each state? So, grouping Names by Provinces.  All data is reading from csv file. I've created the Reader which return List od Breweries.
When i try this:

```
Map<String, List<Breweries>> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
    hashMap = list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Breweries::getProvince));
    for (Map.Entry<String, List<BreweriesPOJO>> stringListEntry : hashMap.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(stringListEntry.getKey());
    }
```

this returns me key(Province) and whole object as a value.

I've been sitting on it for a few hours. I'm out of ideas.

Comment: A `Breweries` is an object that can refer to one ore more `Province`? Is there a reference to `Breweries` in a `Province`? a `Map` of what would you eventually like to get?

Comment: @AlexeyR. my map should looks  like this Map<String,String> -where first string is Names and secound is Province. Now, I grouping Object of breweries by Name. Objects are reading from table -one row, one objects, one column- one object’s field - using openCsv reader.

Comment: Can you give a sample input (csv) and the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

Your example is not correct you have a `HashMap<String, List<Breweries>>` but you expect `hashMap.entrySet()` to return `Set<Map.Entry<String, List<BreweriesPOJO>>`. It should be `Set<Map.Entry<String, List<Breweries>>`. when you do `Map.Entry#getKey` it will return the key in your case the `String` return by `Breweries::getProvince`. If you want the list of the `Breweries` for the current entry use `Map.Entry#getValue`

```java
Map<String, List<Breweries>> hashMap = list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Breweries::getProvince));
for (Map.Entry<String, List<Breweries>> stringListEntry : hashMap.entrySet()) {
    List<Breweries> breweries = stringListEntry.getValue();
}
```

But if you just want the number of Breweries per province you can do this directly like:

```java
Map<String, Long> hashMap = list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Breweries::getProvince, Collectors.counting()));
for (Map.Entry<String, Long> entry : hashMap.entrySet()){
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ": " + entry.getValue() + " Breweries");
}
```